Python based app has file loading problem when window start up
I built a program that needs to be started at window startup and it has problem when loading a file.
for example, let's say that the path of my app is :
 c:\dir1\dir2\app.exe

This app.exe is built by cx_freeze.
And there is a file named :
c:\dir1\dir2\file.json

To make this app run at the beginning of the startup of window, I made a shortcut in the startup directory, and editted the registry using winreg.
The problem is : my app has a code that is named :
 file = open(os.getcwd() + '/file.json','r') 

And when this runs at startup, the path is where the shortcut is, not c:\dir1\dir2\.
Since this app should be distributed to several people, I cannot fix the absolute path by code and that is the most problematic.
What I want is to make my app somehow read c:\dir1\dir2\ when the window start, by making txt file in c:, etc. What is the general solution of this problem ? I think it is matter of my lack of knowledge, not difficulty of problem.

maybe use an absolute path instead of os.getcwd() for example: file_path = r'C:\dir1\dir2\file.json'

If you use "dir" dir2" "dir3" it becomes little bit chaotic. Why don't you explain it completely? We will not copy your folder structure and make it our own... :D

I think the current working directory is not c:\dir1\dir2\ but a different directory where the startup script runs. Try using the value of the __file__ variable and get that path's parent instead of os.getcwd().
Example:
import sys

from os import getcwd
from pathlib import Path

a = getcwd()
this_file_path = sys.executable if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) else __file__
b = Path(this_file_path).parent.absolute()

print(a)
print(b)

upd: I've updated the code snipped based on Python cx_Freeze name __file__ is not defined that stated that __file__ variable might be unavailable or might have unexpected value after freezing.
I've also tested the above solution by freezing my example code with cx-freeze.
The result was:
C:\path\the\executable\was\called\from
C:\path\the\executable\resides


Oh can you please tell me a little bit more details ? Is it okay to just replacing os.getcwd() to file ?

I've added a full example to the post.

@badrosd It was great advice of you. However it did not work also. When windows start, he error log says,  bitmap C:\WINDOWS\system32\file.json not defined . I think the shortcut recognizes its parent route as system folder.

This might help then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937695/python-cx-freeze-name-file-is-not-defined

I've updated the solution, and I also tested it by freezing and running it.

It just workd magically. You are my Von Neumann
